# How to show new spinner according to previous spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner

I am creating an application I have 3 spinner. In the 3rd spinner I have some values, on I particular selected value I want to open a new spinner if I selected particular value from 3rd Spinner that time a new spinner appear else it will hide from screen is this possible in Android ?

Comment: Everything is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no Idea actually how can I do it. I created only three spinner but I don't know how can I do this thing ?

Comment: Yes it is possible by just View visiable or gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as @Mohan suggested, by adding another spinner4 at bottom of spinner3 and make visibility = false, when you select particular value in spinner3 (you can get this by onItemSelectedListener), make spinner4  visibility = true, or else visibility = false.
Here is a sample code:

```
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position==particularPosition){
                        spinner4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        spinner4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding another spinner at bottom of 3rd spinner and make visibility = false, when you select particular value in 3rd spinner (you can get this by onItemSelectedListener), make 4th spinner visibility = true, or else visibility = false.